# Restrict user to type after maximum length

Tags: android, xml

I am restricting the user to type more than 30 char by giving **android:maxLength=30**
and still i can able to type above 30 characters but its not visible..Perfect but the main issue which i am facing here is when i try to delete some characters its deleting only from above 30+ characters which i typed additonally.Based on the stackoverflow answers  **android:inputType="text|textFilter"** && **android:inputType="textNoSuggestions "** its working fine but autofill dictionary is gone...How to restrict the typing above 30+ characters with autofill dictionary

Comment: Thats a bug so once you modified the input type maxLength would work perfectly, preventing users from typing more buffer. Its a bug

Comment: Consider accepting answer if helped any !

Comment: @W4R10CK surely i will accept but these answers didn't met my requirement. but..still i am trying to bring dictionary....

Answer (score 0):

I think input filter is what you are looking for

```
textView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30) });
```

Comment: Its restricted at 30 but i can still able to type when i try to erase its not erasing from 30th character..if i use input filter in xml it will hide the auto dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code to your `EditText`. It will block after limit.

```
 android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Comment: yea its restricting but auto fill dictionary is gone...why?? That's my question

Comment: Thats a bug so once you modified the input type maxLength would work perfectly, preventing users from typing more buffer. Its a bug

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String currentText = editText.getText().toString();
                if(currentText.length() > 30) {
                    editText.setText(currentText.substring(0, 30));
                }
        }

});
```

Comment: Its restricted at 30 but i can still able to type when i try to erase its not erasing from 30th character.

Comment: Maybe put that string operations from "beforeTextChanged" into "afterTextChanged".